# I am getting a "NameError: name 'add' is not defined" error while making a calculator in python

Tags: python, oop, calculator

This is the error I am getting

```
`Select operation.
1.Add
2.Subtract
3.Multiply
4.Divide
Enter choice(1/2/3/4): 1
Enter first number: 1
Enter second number: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 68, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 50, in solve
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

This is what I have done so far

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Feb  6 23:32:23 2023

@author: John
"""

class Calculator:
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, choice, num1, num2):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.choice = choice
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    
    def subtract(self, x, y):
        return x - y
    
    def multiply(self, x, y):
        return x * y
    
    def divide(self, x, y):
        return x / y

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")
    
def solve():
        while True:
            # take input from the user
            choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): ")

            # check if choice is one of the four options
            if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
                try:
                    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
                    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
                    continue

                if choice == '1':
                    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

                elif choice == '2':
                    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

                elif choice == '3':
                    print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

                elif choice == '4':
                    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
        
                # check if user wants another calculation
                # break the while loop if answer is no
                next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
                if next_calculation == "no":
                   break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")
solve()
```

I am getting a "NameError: name 'add' is not defined" error. I am building a calculator program. I think the issue is in the solve function. How do I define the add, subtract, division and multiply methods properly. The caluclator is supposed to take in to inputs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`Calculator` is a class, the methods on it are tied to instances of the class. They're not global functions.

You need to either instantiate a new `Calculator` instance

```py
calculator = Calculator()
# then use like
calculator.add(...)
calculator.subtract(...)
calculator.multiply(...)
calculator.divide(...)
```

or change the methods to be static methods

```py
@staticmethod
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
# repeat on others
# then use like
Calculator.add(...)
Calculator.subtract(...)
Calculator.multiply(...)
Calculator.divide(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your add function (and all the other operations) are defined in the calculator class which your are not referencing. Declare the methods as `@staticmethod` and use `Calculator.add`, `Calculator.subtract` etc. Or Create an instance of the Calculator class and call the functions with the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the class for calculator and haven't created it object, how would you use a class's methods without creating it's object objects??

so first you need to create object then call its methods.
use the code below

```
class Calculator:

    def __init__(self):
      pass

    
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    def subtract(self, x, y):
        return x - y

    def multiply(self, x, y):
        return x * y2

    def divide(self, x, y):
        return x / y

    def solve(self):
        while True:
            # take input from the user
            choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): ")

            # check if choice is one of the four options
            if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
                try:
                    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
                    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
                    continue

                if choice == '1':
                    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", self.add(num1, num2))

                elif choice == '2':
                    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", self.subtract(num1, num2))

                elif choice == '3':
                    print(num1, "*", num2, "=", self.multiply(num1, num2))

                elif choice == '4':
                    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", self.divide(num1, num2))
    
                # check if user wants another calculation
                # break the while loop if answer is no
                next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
                if next_calculation == "no":
                   break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

calculator = Calculator()
calculator.solve()
```